# Can we use JAVAFX code inside a SWING code?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I know that we can use swing modules inside a JavaFX applicaion but can we do the reverse.
I want to use JAVAFX effects and animation and also stylesheets inside my Java Swing code. Are there any samples avaialable?

Comment: For a quick code example have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374365/integrating-javafx-2-0-webview-into-a-swing-java-se-6-application/8413289#8413289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a brief tutorial [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ixmal/archive/2011/06/02/using-javafx-20-inside-swing-applications).

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaFX 2.0 Beta, it is cleaner. A good example is SwingJavaFXChart, available in the <SDK>/apps directory.