# JApplet Java SE 6 + JavaFX 2.0 WebView

Tags: java, webview, applet, noclassdeffounderror, javafx-2

I'm trying to add JavaFX 2.0 WebView in my applet

I added JFXPanel and the program compiles just fine

```
    import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
    ....
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
```

With parameters: javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar" C:\test.java

But when I try to run the program, I get an error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel

Java Plug-in 10.3.1.255
Using JRE version 1.7.0_03-b05 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
JavaFX 2.0
This tutorial also gives a similar error:
[Integrating JavaFX 2.0 WebView into a Swing Java SE 6 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374365/integrating-javafx-2-0-webview-into-a-swing-java-se-6-application)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/Parent

Comment: Did you try running the application with java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\rt\lib\jfxrt.jar" <FullyQualifiedClassName>?