# javafx webview crashes into color boxes

Tags: webview, javafx

when using the webview in javafx it randomly stops rendering and switches everything out for random color boxes.
It spits out this error at me

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Kodukas\IdeaProjects\Starling Browser\out\production\Starling Browser;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain net.makerimages.starling.src.Main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSDrawable.create(PPSDrawable.java:54)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.createCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:148)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.createCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:62)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.ImagePool.checkOut(ImagePool.java:166)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.Renderer.getCompatibleImage(Renderer.java:118)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:153)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:62)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.Effect.getCompatibleImage(Effect.java:491)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$Layer.<init>(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1169)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$ClipLayer.<init>(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1226)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:234)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:205)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:67)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint2GC(WebPage.java:661)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:640)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:71)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:188)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced saveState/restoreState
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.dispose(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1564)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.disposeGraphics(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:32)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:642)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:71)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:188)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSDrawable.create(PPSDrawable.java:54)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.createCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:148)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.createCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:62)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.ImagePool.checkOut(ImagePool.java:166)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.Renderer.getCompatibleImage(Renderer.java:118)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:153)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSRenderer.getCompatibleImage(PPSRenderer.java:62)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.Effect.getCompatibleImage(Effect.java:491)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$Layer.<init>(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1169)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext$ClipLayer.<init>(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1226)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.setClip(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:234)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.GraphicsDecoder.decode(GraphicsDecoder.java:205)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.WCRenderQueue.decode(WCRenderQueue.java:67)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint2GC(WebPage.java:661)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:640)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:71)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:188)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unbalanced saveState/restoreState
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext.dispose(WCGraphicsPrismContext.java:1564)
at com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.disposeGraphics(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:32)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:642)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:71)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:204)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:420)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:201)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:40)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(BaseNode.java:1145)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:117)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(AbstractPainter.java:188)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:108)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

    Process finished with exit code 0
```

This has no refrence to my code which can be seen here:

```
package net.makerimages.starling.src;

import com.sun.webpane.platform.graphics.WCGraphicsContext;
import com.sun.webpane.sg.prism.WCGraphicsPrismContext;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode; 
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import net.makerimages.starling.src.window.TopBar;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Main extends Application {
  public static TextField addressBar;
  public static ToolBar toolBar;
  public static Stage stg;
  int height = 25;
public static WebView browser;
public static WebEngine webEngine;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

     browser = new WebView();
     webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    toolBar=new ToolBar();
    toolBar.setPrefHeight(height);
    toolBar.setMinHeight(height);
    toolBar.setMaxHeight(height);
    toolBar.getItems().add(new TopBar());
     addressBar=new TextField("Enter a URL");
     addressBar.setId("addressBar");

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( WCGraphicsContext.class.getName() );
    logger.setLevel( Level.OFF);


    addressBar.setOnKeyPressed( new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                loadWebsite(addressBar.getText());

                keyEvent.consume();
            }
        }
    });






    BorderPane root=new BorderPane();
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("url:http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/SUNNYDAY/animals/jpg/32/starling_bird_icon.jpg"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Starling Browser");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 700));
    root.setBottom(addressBar);
    root.setAlignment(addressBar, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    root.setCenter(browser);


    root.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("starlingElements.css").toExternalForm());
   root.setTop(toolBar);


    primaryStage.show();
    webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");

    stg=primaryStage;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

 public static void loadWebsite(String url)
 {
    webEngine.load("http://"+ url);

 }
}
```

I have no ideas to make it stop, cany anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I see no flickering when running on `1.7.0u40`. You could try

- Running it on JDK 8 EA to make sure this is JDK 7 specific problem.
- Removing stylesheets (I removed this line to make it runnable).
- Removing `TopBar` import to see if this is the cause (I don't have it, so I removed this line).

Comment: JDK 8 works, however the images on the page(instagram profile) intend to refresh every few seconds.. full code can also be seen at https://bitbucket.org/makerimages/starling-browser

Comment: I checked your demo at instagram - the rendering/browsing experience is a bit different - it produces less fps, so image transitions are less smooth, but that's it. Everything else is just the same, I see no serious issues. (Which is great for a `WebView` as a technology!) I'm running JDK 8 b116.

Comment: oh, but the images flicker for me, reloading themselves it seems every few sec. any way to increase the fps?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm running on Windows 8 x64, no flickering. GPU acceleration for WebView seems being supported on all platforms, so the fps problem could also be improved at instagram by i.e. switching to CSS transitions (if they are not using them). This can also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762979/performance-of-webview-in-javafx?rq=1 - I don't if x32 vs x64 performance difference is still there.

Comment: I would suggest you to file a bug at their JIRA: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/login.jsp. Guys at Oracle have tons of work to do, but this may be fixed soon if it gets a priority.