# Is it possible to change WebView of JavaFX to Chrome

Tags: java, html, javafx, java-8, javafx-webengine

We are trying to create a desktop application which opens url with html5 canvas. We implemented it using Java 8 JavaFX. But we experiencing bad response in rendering of sketches.
This working fine in Chrome browser. Is it possible to embed chrome browser in JavaFx application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it possible to change WebView of JavaFX to Chrome

No.

> Is it possible to embed chrome browser in JavaFx application?

Yes.

Try [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef) from the chromium embedded project instead of WebView.

For a commercial solution, [JxBrowser](https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/jxbrowser-support/documentation/quick-start-guide-javafx) advertises Chromium support for JavaFX applications.

I have not used either of JxBrowser or JCEF, so I have no further details or advice on how to use them or whether or not they would be fit for your purpose.

Comment: I can confirm JxBrowser works great. But did you really manage to embed JCEF in a JavaFX application? To my knowledge it only works for Swing.

Comment: Last time I checked the comment was "There are no plans to support it currently. External contributions are welcome." http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=14639

Comment: As noted in my answer "I have not used either of JxBrowser or JCEF".

Answer (score 0):

No, currently there's no such option. [Oracle discussion](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2479066)

However, you can deploy your application in a browser - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102000/javafx-can-it-really-be-deployed-in-a-browser) is the discussion about this.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot embed Chrome browser in webview of JavaFX.

Refer this link: [Performance of WebView in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762979/performance-of-webview-in-javafx)

You will get an idea about its performance relative to other browsers.