# JavaFX Pane inside of a Tab

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I want to extend a Class from Pane and then use the `setContent()` method from a tab from `TabPane` to display the Pane inside this Tab. It worked in `Swing` when I extended from `JPanel` but if I try something similar in `JavaFX` it only displays the tab itself and stays empty below.

[image: Image of the tab]

I want to handle the content of the tabs in separate classes, am I doing something completely wrong here?

Swing version:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Home extends JFrame{
  private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
  private Example ex = new Example();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Home h1 = new Home();
    h1.ex= new Example();
    h1.jTabbedPane1.add("test",h1.ex);
  } // end of main

  public Home() { 
    // Frame-Initialisierung
    super();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    setSize(200,200);
    Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (d.width - getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (d.height - getSize().height) / 2;
    setLocation(x, y);
    setResizable(false);

    Container cp = getContentPane();
    cp.setLayout(null);
    // Anfang Komponenten

    jTabbedPane1.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    cp.add(jTabbedPane1);

    setVisible(true);
  } // end of public home
} // end of class Home

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example extends JPanel {
  private JList jList1 = new JList();
  private DefaultListModel jList1Model = new DefaultListModel();
  private JScrollPane jList1ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList1);

  public Example(){
    super();
    setLayout(null);
    jList1.setModel(jList1Model);
    jList1ScrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);

    add(jList1ScrollPane);

    }

} // end of class Example
```

Not working in JavaFX version:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Home extends Application {


  private TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
  private Example ex;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

     primaryStage.setTitle("TEST");

     Pane layout = new Pane();

     tabpane.setLayoutX(-8);
     tabpane.setLayoutY(24);
     tabpane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);

      Tab tab = new Tab();
      tab.setText("new tab");
      tab.setContent(new Rectangle(200,200));
      this.ex = new Example();
      tab.setContent(ex);
      tabpane.getTabs().add(tab);

     layout.getChildren().add(tabpane);

     Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 500, 500);


     scene.getStylesheets().clear();
     scene.getStylesheets().add(Home.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

     primaryStage.setScene(scene);
     primaryStage.setResizable(false);


     primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class Example extends Pane{

     ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();


    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


     ArrayList<String> arraytest = new ArrayList<String>();
     arraytest.add("test1");
     arraytest.add("test2");

    ObservableList<String> test = FXCollections.observableArrayList(arraytest);

    list.setItems(test);
    list.setLayoutX(10);
    list.setLayoutY(10);
    list.setPrefWidth(270);
    list.setPrefHeight(270); 

     getChildren().add(list);

    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you embedding, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/44087027/230513), or porting?

Comment: I just extended a class from JPanel and then added it like `jTabbedPane.add("nameOfTheTab",ClassExtendedFromJPanel);` to the JTabbedPane

Comment: It sounds like you want to port an existing Swing program to JavaFX.  Please edit your question to include a [mcve] for  each of both the original Swing program and the attempted JavaFX version, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31909941/230513).

Comment: done. I think the problem is at the example.java but i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong there

Comment: Directly using or extending Pane is the equivalent of doing `setLayout(null)` in Swing.  Both are very bad ideas.  It’s not clear what you’re trying to do, since your JavaFX code is adding a `List<String>` to a Pane’s children, which is not allowed, but I suspect a standard layout like VBox may give you what you want; no need to extend any standard Java classes.

Comment: Kudos for not just one but _two_ [mcve]s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Swing example is incorrectly synchronized and suffers from an [inflexible layout having absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5621338/230513). The example should be discarded except to observe that [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) "may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of children is required." In this case, your JavaFX example does not.

In the JavaFX variation below, `Example` constructs the desired `ListView` and makes it available via the `getContent()` method. `Home` then uses that content for the tab. Resize the enclosing stage to see the effect.

```
tab.setContent(example.getContent());
```

As an aside, the `private static class Example` is semantically equivalent to a class having [*package-private*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) access, making it easy to test *in situ* and later refactor into a separate class.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane.TabClosingPolicy;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102580/230513 */
public class Home extends Application {

    private TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
    private Example example = new Example();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        tabpane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabClosingPolicy.UNAVAILABLE);
        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("Tab One");
        tab.setContent(example.getContent());
        tabpane.getTabs().add(tab);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tabpane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class Example {

        ListView<String> view = new ListView<>();

        public Example() {
            ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3");
            view.setItems(list);
        }

        public ListView<String> getContent() {
            return view;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! thank you very much for explaining this to me in detail. It was very helpful. Helping me much since I'm still very new to programming.

Comment: My last question is how do i add something like buttons in the Example class? i cant add them to any scene because it doesnt use a Pane or something similar.

Comment: Instead of `getContent()` returning `ListView`, let it return a suitable `Pane` subclass to which you've added the desired controls.

Comment: If i change the return type to `Pane` and the return value to `return new Pane();` just to test this, I get various errors if I try to run the code but while coding in NetBeans I get no errors displayed..

Comment: Not `Pane`, but a _subclass_ of `Pane`, such as `AnchorPane` or `BorderPane`, etc.

Comment: Fail.. worked perfectly with `StackPane`, you are a godsent, dude!