# Launching a browser from a desktop application

Tags: java, windows, browser, java-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser)  - This is totally not a duplicate.  I want to be able to reference a tab in the browser not just launch the browser.

I have a desktop application that has a button with an action that opens up a new browser with a specific URL.  Every time I press the button it opens up a new window/tab.  I want it to refresh the window/tab, if it is already open and if the URL is the same, instead of always opening a new one.  The code to launch the initial window is pretty straight forward:

```
final String errMsg = "Error attempting to launch web browser";
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name"); 
try{ 
    if (osName.startsWith("Windows")) 
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + "www.stackoverflow.com");
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errMsg + "\n" + e.toString());
}
```

I was thinking maybe I could name the window/tab so when the code is launched it tries to find the name and refresh it if exists.  But I am having troubles finding a solution like that. Additionally, is the way I am currently doing it acceptable?

Comment: @plasma147 - I should mention I am using Java 5, so that solution won't work for me.

Comment: @plasma147 It's not an exact dup, the OP wants the same browser tab to be refreshed every time it's launched from the Java GUI app.

Comment: @plasma147 By the way I love tardigrades too, any animal that can survive in space gets my vote. :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a webserver component to your application. Then start a browser pointing to a page generated by your webserver and use AJAX to refresh browser content upon button click.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this as a basis :

[Getting java gui to open a webpage in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602032/getting-java-gui-to-open-a-webpage-in-web-browser)

to open a browser in a non-os specific way.

It probably doesn't give you that level of control over a browser.

Have you considered using JeditorPane or if you need extra javascript support possible including a javafx webview (which is based on webkit):
[Integrating JavaFX 2.0 WebView into a Swing Java SE 6 Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374365/integrating-javafx-2-0-webview-into-a-swing-java-se-6-application)

Comment: Ah, I guess javafx integration won't work with java s.e 6. JEditorPane would work - you could download the html and render it as you want. The renderer isn't great on it though

Comment: I am not sure rendering it myself will meet the requirements.  I wish we were already Java 6 but we are still a year or so away from moving to that :/