# Embed browser with session data in Java app?

Tags: java

Is it possible to embed a browser within a desktop java application that can handle session data and possibly cookies? It should be able to handle a login to eBay and paypal websites.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249/is-there-a-way-to-embed-a-browser-in-java

Comment: I saw that question but there was no mention of ability to login to websites.

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Surely *one* of the solutions posted can act as a full-featured UA (e.g. supports cookies) ..

Comment: If the goal is searching, selecting and buying items why not use eBay APIs instead? http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java FX 2.xx has [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) which is an embedded browser. If you are working in a Swing environment, you can still [embed that Java FX 2.x component in a Swing panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374365/integrating-javafx-2-0-webview-into-a-swing-java-se-6-application).

ps: I don't know for sure if it can handle login to eBay and Paypal but I would have thought it does because it is built on [WebKit engine](http://www.webkit.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [SWT Browser](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) class. It uses an available native browser, and it supports everything you should need.